# React Native Qr code and camera not working properly in IOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-camera

I am using react-native-camera and react-native-qrcode-scanner libraries for scanning qr codes in my app. In android I have tested this and it was working fine, but in IOS I am facing lot of issues. The camera opens successfully on first attempt but after scanning the camera gets freezes and then a blank screen appears instead of camera. I have also given permissions in info.plist file in Xcode related to camera. Here is the code for the QRcode scan which I am using in the app

```js
render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <QRCodeScanner
          onRead={this.onSuccess.bind(this)}
          showMarker={true}
     />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Current versions in my app -
react-native - 0.57.5
react-native-camera - 1.10.1
react-native-qr-code-scanner - 1.1.2

Any answer or suggestions would be helpful to me Thanks.

Comment: I'm using your react-native version and the latest react-native-qrcode-scanner, but my react-native-camera is 1.6.3 and I have no issues on both iOS and Android. Have you tried setting a `reactivate` prop in `<QRCodeScanner />`? Or try to post your onSuccess() method

Comment: I tried 1.6.3 version also but still facing the issue. I came to know that its not the blank screen appearing but the camera is taking time to load/render on the screen. Then I check the memory leak in the application through xcode. Is using componentDidUpdate() in my code without componentWillUnmount() method produces memory leaks??

Comment: Can you please post your `onSuccess()` method ?